# Java best way/recommended data structure to represent date in a month, e.g, 01 January

Tags: java, date

There is often a task to represent a month, e.g,

> January

, or a date in a month, e.g.,

> 01 January

, in a generic way, without specifying the year.

A caveat: quite often the captured data (e.g, user choice or input of other type) needs storing in a DB - SLQ or NoSQ. And that is subsequently used for reporting, for example, using date range aggregation.

Is there any consensus/recommendations on which Java data type is best to use for the above scenario?

I see the following 3 options:

1. Use Java Date, within the "0th" year, e.g, 01 January 1970, and then
   use  Date operations to extract only the required fields (DAY,
   MONTH), and strip out all the rest. Libraries such as Joda or Java8
   come handy here. Saving to DB is straightforward here, although the
   programmatic overhead could be quite high.
2. Use contrived data type, e.g., ENUM, to list all months, or use numeric value for a month and provide mapping, then parse and shoe-horn further to capture the day in a month. Mapping to a DB field is not too difficult.
3. Use String, e.g, "01 January". Seems straightforward enough.

nos.2 and 3 could be less programming-intensive, but an added disadvantage that such a dates may be clunky when used in reporting, as aggregation by time period is not straightforward.

Any suggestions/thoughts on the above?

Edit:

It looks like the option #1 is the best (most flexible, least resistance, easiest for persistence, and best for subsequent reporting). New Java libraries make data manipulation and field extraction a relative doddle.

Comment: The only aspect I'd like further discussion on is the following: Do we need to set year back to 1970 when we don't care for capturing a year, or are there any other approaches that are better (e.g. using current year or perhaps disregarding year alltogether somehow (how?)). Which one is easier with modern Java libraries - if possible, with examples for comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `java.time.MonthDay` provides a ready made class, so you don't need to create your own. It'll also be usable with other `java.time` functionality, so that's probably your best bet. It should be fairly easy to persist as well.

```
MonthDay birthday = MonthDay.of(Month.JANUARY, 11);
```

Comment: just pay attention to the docs, only new library versions can talk java8 java.time. For example, earlier Hibernate versions would require a helping stick in the hibernate-java8 library.

Comment: @aepure Any other option would still require additional work with regards to persistence. This is the path of least resistance.

Comment: agree, the "pay attention" was for people reading your answer

Comment: FYI, much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the ThreeTen-Backport project. Further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project.

Answer (score 3):

The other two Answers describing the the java.time classes `Month` and `MonthDay` are correct and are well-advised. Similar is `YearMonth`.

Study the class documentation to find some handy methods. For example, [`Month::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) localizes the name of the month. Another example, you can get a date, a `LocalDate` from `MonthDay` by passing a year to the method `atYear`.

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes found outside the java.time package. These old classes are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

For textual representation of such date-time values, look to the many formats defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

For month-day, the format is `--MM-DD`. For example, January 23 is:

> --01-23

These ISO 8601 are especially useful for data exchange between systems.

The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.parse( "--01-23" ) ;
String output = md.toString() ;  // --01-23
```

For presentation to users, your audience may be amenable to reading the ISO 8601 formats. If not, you can generate strings from your java.time objects. Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM dd" , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = md.format( f );
```

> janv. 23

Or for `Locale.US`:

> Jan. 23

## Use objects, not strings & integers

Use objects from the java.time classes whenever possible rather than crude strings and mere integers.

For months, do not use 1-12 numbers. Instead of `3` for the month of March, use `Month.MARCH`. Instead of `04 July` for the month-day of July 4th, use the `MonthDay` object generated by `MonthDay.of( Month.JULY , 4 )`.

Pass around such objects as method arguments rather than passing strings or numbers. Use these java.time types to define member fields when composing a class.

Using such objects gives you these benefits:

- [Type-safety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety)
  ( avoid accidentally using the string of "tuesday" as a month )
- Ensures valid values
  ( no mistaken month of `13` )
- Makes your code more self-documenting and easier to read.

## JDBC

For exchanging data with a database, JDBC drivers compliant with JDBC 4.2 can work directly with the java.time types. Call:

- `PreparedStatement::setObject`
- `ResultSet::getObject`

No need to use the java.sql types not strings for fetching and storing date-time values.

As for your specific problem of string and retrieving month-day values, we have a problem as standard SQL does not define such a type. I would use a text or varchar type to store a seven-character string in the ISO 8601 format discussed above: `--MM-DD`.  Call the `MonthDay` methods `parse` and `toString`.

These standard formats are wisely designed to be chronological when sorted alphabetically. So sorting a ResultSet in the database will work well as will queries for a range of month-day values.

Answer (score 2):

The 3 options you are considering are already there in a  [Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) since Java 8

```
Month month = Month.valueOf("July".toUpperCase());
System.out.println(month);
System.out.println(Month.AUGUST);
```